# Complex SQL queries

Tags: sql

I have a table called

Subscriptions (user_name varchar(50) , video_name varchar(50), watched_date date)

ravi      simsons         2016-01-01
ravi      dailyshow       2016-02-15
nitin     dailyshow       2016-02-24
nitin     simsons         2016-02-25
sam     simsons           2016-03-04
sam       dailyshow       2016-03-04
mat          simsons         2016-04-06
cranw  simsons         2016-04-15
cranw     dailyshow       2016-04-17

simsons and dailyshow are the names of the video

I need to find the distinct count of user_names who watched Simsons before dailyshow.

I'm struggling to do with a self-join and case statement but still cannot get the correct query.

Comment: What have you tried and what were your results?  Post some code, or better yet setup an sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with separate inline views for each video_name and joining them on user_name. Then use a `where` clause for the watched_date condition.

```
select count(distinct sdaily.user_name)
from (select * from subscriptions where video_name = 'simsons') ssim
join (select * from subscriptions where video_name = 'dailyshow') sdaily
on sdaily.user_name = ssim.user_name
where ssim.watched_date < sdaily.watched_date
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is easiest using aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select s.user_name,
             min(case when s.video_name = 'simsons' then s.watched_date end) as s_date,
             max(case when s.video_name = 'dailyshow' then s.watched_date end) as ds_date
     from subscriptions
     group by s.user_name
    ) u
where s_date < ds_date;
```